# fair-indexed tournament

Tags: graph-theory

Let's say that two tournaments $T$ and $T'$ with vertex respectivally $T_1,T_2,....T_n$ and $T'_1,T'_2,....T'_n$  are in the same score-class iff there is a $n$-permutation $s$, such that for any $i\in \left\{1,2,....n\right\}$, $T_i$ and $T'_{s(i)}$ have the same number of victory.

Let's say that a tournament whose vertex are $T_1,T_2,...,T_n$ is fair-indexed iff for any $i\in \left\{1,2,3,....,n\right\}$ there exists $j\in \left\{i,i+1,...,n\right\}$ such that for any $k>i$, $T_i$ beats $T_k$ iff $k>j$.

> Is there a fair-indexed tournament in any score-class?

(I would also be glad to  kwow if there is already a standard appelation for "fair-indexed", or if the question has been studied already, if it is the case i will edit)

The mathematician who presented me the problem (in quite a different form) told me that  it would solve a problem of interpolation of multivalued polynomes, that has only been solved for the characteristic zero - I'll give some precisions when I will get them, if anyone is interested... anyway I find the question for itself nice enough to be asked and investigated.

Comment: Sorry about my stupid "answer". I will try to think intelligently about your question.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I looked if the question was clear after your answer and thanks to it, I edited  "iff" insted of "if"^^

Comment: From looking at very small examples I got the idea that maybe there is always a fair indexing with $s_1\ge s_2\ge\cdots\ge s_n$ where $s_i$ is the score (out-degree) of the vertex $T_i$. This was a wrong idea, as shown by the example $$\{6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,3\}.$$

Comment: @bof : indeed, if it was true, by symetry, it would be true as well for increasing sequences. The smallest example that does not work monotonally (both increasingly and decreasingly) is $\left\{2,2,3,3,3,4,4\right\}$

Comment: What symmetry is that? I learned long ago that it doesn't work for increasing sequences such as $\{1,1,1,3\}$, but only recently learned that decreasing sequences don't work either.

Comment: Sorry i made a confusion with the symetry thing!  Is it a famous problem ? (because you wrote ""I lerarned long ago..."

Comment: I meant *relatively* long ago, i.e., a few days after you posted the question.

Comment: By the way, what happens if your "fair indexing" requirement is strengthened, so as to require both your condition "if $i\lt j\lt k$ and $T_i$ beats $T_j$ then $T_i$ beats $T_k$" and simultaneously "if $i\lt j\lt k$ and $T_k$ beats $T_i$ then $T_k$ beats $T_j$"? Do you have a counterexample to that?

Comment: If i don't mistake i think 22225555 is a counterexample...

Comment: Lets call the strengthened a bifair indexation. I thought once if score (wied as a increasing fonction) that does not increase of mire than 1 might have a bifair indexation tournament in the class that they define. (In the counterexample i gave, the score is increasing by 3 units from 2 to 5)   I don't know if the statement of bifairity for the 0 or 1 increasing score is  true or not... but i'm going to think about it!

Comment: by the way the tournament that are bifair indexable (lets call them BFI), are maybe intersting to study, as well as the set of 0 or 1 incresing score  (lets call them ZOOI) The Zooi are intersting because 1) it seems that almost every tournament is Zooi 2) you can get all the score  by  iterated substitutions of Zooi in a zooi. I will be more precise in both 1) and 2) if you ask me^^

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample!